# Create hashmap with arraylist of hashmap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have the following structure

```
{
    "abc":[
        {
            "bc":"52",
            "gd":"jjksa"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I need to create the same structure from the client side and send the data similar like the above format. I am assuming the structure to be something like this.

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> hashmap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<new HashMap<String, String>()>>();

HashMap<String, String> obj1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();

obj1.put("bc", "52");
obj1.put("gd", "jjksa");

arraylist.add(obj1);

hashmap.put("metrics", arraylist)
```

Anyone who can help me create the proper map as shown in the above example.

Comment: Having a `HashMap` of `ArrayList` of `HashMap` is a sign of a bad design.

Comment: Use a JSON processor such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

Comment: @MarounMaroun So can you suggest a better design for the above example

Comment: @user850234 You might want to consider having a class that implements some of the complicated logic you have there.

Comment: For your own clarity it might be better to define your own class which implements a `HashMap` and `ArrayList` so you have proper names for the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code worked for me. However the suggestion that you guys have put forward is surely valuable. I will make the changes accordingly to make the structure better.

```
HashMap<String, Object> hashmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

HashMap<String, String> obj1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

ArrayList arraylist = new ArrayList();

obj1.put("bc", "52");
obj1.put("gd", "jjksa");

arraylist.add(obj1);

hashmap.put("metrics", arraylist);

Gson json = new Gson();

System.out.print(json.toJson(hashmap));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON processor such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson):

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

// ...

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(hashmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple the HashMap's toString method prints the value excatly like your json but without the double-quotes("). :)

sp00m's answer works perfectly. In addition to that you could also use google's [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.google.gson.Gson;


public class GsonParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> hashmap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>();

        HashMap<String, String> obj1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        obj1.put("bc", "52");
        obj1.put("gd", "jjksa");

        arraylist.add(obj1);

        //Hashmap toString
        hashmap.put("metrics", arraylist);
        System.out.println(hashmap); //Prints : {metrics=[{bc=52, gd=jjksa}]}

        //Jackson Example
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(hashmap);
        System.out.println(json); //Prints : {"metrics":[{"bc":"52","gd":"jjksa"}]}

        //Gson Example
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json2 = gson.toJson(hashmap);
        System.out.println(json2); //Prints : {"metrics":[{"bc":"52","gd":"jjksa"}]}
    }

}
```